# Spring Boot: Configuration Scan missing classes due to "weird" setup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

We setup an ETL project in a sort of messy way just to get a job done:

This project has dependencies on several other spring projects, so we included those projects as dependencies. These projects contain their own @Configuration classes that could cause conflicts. I'm in a state now where I setup a Dynamic Repository in my ETL project but it is not being autowired, throwing an error:

> constructor in com.myetl.service.impl.ErrorServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.myetl.repository.ProjectErrorRepository' that could not be found.

I see earlier in the console when I startup the application that it is treating it as a Redis Repository:

> RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data Redis - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.myetl.repository.ProjectErrorRepository. If you want this repository to be a Redis repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisHash (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.KeyValueRepository.

I don't have Redis configuration anywhere in my base project, but it is definitely there in one of my Dependencies.

I tried a few different things but nothing works. For example, using an exclude filter:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DifferentProjectConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan(includeFilters =
               @ComponentScan.Filter(type= FilterType.REGEX,
                                     pattern = "com\\.etl\\..*"),
               excludeFilters =
               @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
                                     value = {OtherProjectRedisConfiguration.class}))
public class ProjectsMigrationApplication {
...
```

If I comment out the repository the application loads fine, including controllers and service beans. This problem only seems to target the repository which I want to be a MySql JPA repo. Here is the definition of my Repository (I tried it with and without the @Repository annotation):

```
package com.etl.repository;

import com.etl.domain.ProjectError;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

public interface ProjectErrorRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<ProjectError, Long> {

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="project_error")
@Data
public class ProjectError {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "project_error_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String errMsg;

    @Column(name = "user_email")
    private String userEmail;
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "migrationEntityManagerFactory", basePackageClasses = {
        ProjectError.class}, repositoryBaseClass = ProjectErrorRepository.class)
public class ProjectMigrationJpaConfig {

    @Bean(name = "migrationEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean migrationEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages(ProjectError.class)
                .build();
    }

}
```

What is the best way to diagnose this type of error in a labyrinthine project to understand what Spring is doing behind the scenes?

Comment: It's specifically warning you that it _could not_ treat it as a Redis repository. To make certain, though, change from `PagingAndSortingRepository` to `JpaRepository` and see if that clears it up. If not, then it's a general scanning issue entirely unrelated to Redis.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are pulling in Redis as a transitive dependency from another project. What you are likely wrestling with is the autoconfig.

Try excluding the Redis autoconfiguration from your project and see what that does.

```
    @SpringBootApplication(exclude = { RedisAutoConfiguration.class, RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class })
```

Comment: I did try that as (confusingly) indicated in my question which shows an exclude. I tried adding specific redis configuration there and got an error: "The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes". Maybe I can exclude redis at the maven pom level...

Comment: @IcedDante Could you post what you used as exclusion and what the stack trace was? Does behavior change if you change the repository type?